# React Native: tabBarVisible option set to false but not hidding the the tabBar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using React Navigation `v5` but the when i set the option `tabBarVisible` to false the `tabBar` is not hidding. Here is a piece of code that is not working. I don't know what's wrong.

```
..

  <Tabs.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptions} initialRouteName="Home">
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarVisible: false, // <-- This not working
          tabBarIcon: (props) => (
            <TabIcon
              {...props}
              title="Home"
              Icon={{
                name: "home",
                IconComponent: AntDesign,
              }}
            />
          ),
        })}
      />
...
```

Any suggessions.

Comment: in the `screenOptions` you can set prop `headerShown` to false like `screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}`

Comment: I'm not intrested in the header, I'm interested in the tabbar but thanks buddy. I've also tried that and it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work with the latest version of the package:

```
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Settings"
    component={SettingsScreen}
    options={{ tabBarStyle: { display: 'none' } }}
  />
```

Comment: thanks, when i use your suggestions i'm, i'm losing styles as i go back to the home tab, but i'm going to give you a thanks to appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.
.
.
const TabNavigator = ({ routeName }: Props) => {
  const hideBottomTab =
    routeName === "Login" ||
    routeName === "Register" 

  return (
    <Tabs.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarStyle: {
          display: hideBottomTab ? "none" : "flex",
        },
      }}
    >
.
.
.
```